# Send push to Android by C# using Firebase and get response

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I see other questions about send notifications from c# to android using firebase and  it works.
Now I want to recieve that and  answer  from android until it continuous other proceses code.

```
public void SendNotification( SEG_USER  user)
    {
        WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        //serverKey - Key from Firebase cloud messaging server  
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "mykey"));
        //Sender Id - From firebase project setting  
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "mySendId"));
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var payload = new
        {
            to = "myTokenDevice",
            priority = "high",
            content_available = true,
            notification = new
            {
                body = "Acceso Usuario ["+user.UsuarioID+"] "+ user.UsuarioNombre,
                title = "Acceso al Sistema",
                badge = 2,
                icon = "https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/key.png"
            },
            data = new
            {
                codigo = user.UsuarioID,
                nombreUsuario = user.UsuarioNombre
            }
        };

        string postbody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload).ToString();
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postbody);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (dataStreamResponse != null) using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            //result.Response = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Send Notification to android (✓)
2. Manage and processes with a method in android app and had a result or paremeter (✓)
3. Send result(2.) toc# (✗) like that (`var resp = SendNotification(user);`)

But i want to receive and answer

somethin like that

var resp = SendNotification(user);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could save a response to database
and in the app could get a response from database.
The information will be in Database.